# Is there any documentation about build.dart?

Tags: dart

Based on how web_ui projects work, it looks like the IDE will run any build.dart file in the project as soon as some file is changed (or saved?). Is there any documentation about what arguments are passed to that script by the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's now an article on [Build.dart and the Dart Editor Build System](http://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/build.html) available on http://www.dartlang.org.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any official documentation, so this information is taken from `build` implementation in `web_ui/component_build.dart`, valid for version 0.5.3_r22223:

here are the arguments that `build` function understands:

- `clean` - delete all generated files
- `machine` - use machine readable format (json) for output
- `changed` - list of file which have been changed
- `removed` - file which has been removed
- `full` - rebuild all files

When one or more files are changed of deleted, the editor calls `build.dart` script with arguments `--machine` and list of changed/removed files, e.g.:

arguments when some files were changed:

```
--machine --changed=web\out\webui_test.css --changed=web\out\webui_test.dart
```

arguments when some files were removed:

```
--machine --removed=web\xclickcounter.dart --removed=web\xclickcounter.html
```

Of course, one call can contain both changed and removed files.

BTW, if you want to stop automatic building, just right click on `build.dart` file in files explorer window of the editor, and click `Don't run build.dart`

Comment: The original call seems to be done in http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/editor/tools/plugins/com.google.dart.tools.core/src/com/google/dart/tools/core/internal/builder/BuildDartParticipant.java

Comment: There are also hints in http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/experimental/lib_v2_io/dart/samples/buildhook2/build.dart